# How to consolidate rows of data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to consolidate rows when they have the same ID, Order, and Class. However, the consolidated row needs sum the length, AND input the correct begin and end. So the consolidated row will have the begin value of the first row, and the end value of the last row Please check the image to see what I mean.

I'm pretty sure I can achieve the summing of the length using SUMIF, but I can't figure out how to input the correct begin and end values into the consolidated row.

Is this even possible with excel? I can't use pivot tables because I'm not simply trying sum the length, I want the columns to remain the same, just to consolidate the rows accordingly. Any help will be much appreciated!

The left is what I have, the right is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, it seems the `begin` and `end` that you want are the `min` and `max` respectively, and I used that in the approach.

Relatively simple to do with Power Query, which is available in Excel 2010+.

- Select the ID, Order and Class columns
- `Group By`

  - For Aggregations have min of begin; max of end; and sum of length
- Move the Class column back to the end

**Voila!**

[image]

This can all be done quickly from the UI

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Order", Int64.Type}, {"begin", Int64.Type}, {"end", Int64.Type}, {"length", Int64.Type}, {"class", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Order", "class"}, {{"Begin", each List.Min([begin]), type number}, {"End", each List.Max([end]), type number}, {"Length", each List.Sum([length]), type number}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"ID", "Order", "Begin", "End", "Length", "class"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

For completeness:  If, perchance, you really need to use the First and Last Rows within each group for `Begin` and `End`, instead of `Min/Max`, you can use the following code.

In the `group by` step, instead of aggregating begin/end by max/min, you choose an aggregation of `All Rows`.  This will create a table which includes the begin and end entries for each group.  You can then extract the first and last entries using the `List.First` and `List.Last` functions.

The code for the custom columns:

```
List.First(Table.Column([#"Start/End"],"begin"))
List.Last(Table.Column([#"Start/End"],"end"))
```

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Order", Int64.Type}, {"begin", Int64.Type}, {"end", Int64.Type}, {"length", Int64.Type}, {"class", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Order", "class"}, {{"Length", each List.Sum([length]), type number}, {"Start/End", each _, type table [ID=number, Order=number, begin=number, end=number, length=number, class=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Begin", each List.First(Table.Column([#"Start/End"],"begin"))),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "End", each List.Last(Table.Column([#"Start/End"],"end"))),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Start/End"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"ID", "Order", "Begin", "End", "Length", "class"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

By the way, you can come pretty close with a regular Pivot Table (especially if you can use Min/Max for the begin/end). It's not as flexible, though, and I don't think you can order the columns the way you have shown.

Below is a simple pivot table.

You drag ID, Order and class to the Rows area.
You drag Begin, End and Length to the Values area applying Min, Max and Sum.

Then Show the layout in Tabular form; turn off the grand totals and subtotals, and you have:

[image]

Comment: I think Begin and End are "first row" and "last row", not Min/Max

Comment: @TimWilliams That's what he wrote, but Min/Max returns the same result, and is simpler if they are sorted low to high within the groups. It can certainly be done by row number in PQ, but may add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: How about: https://radacad.com/grouping-in-power-query-getting-the-last-item-in-each-group

Comment: @TimWilliams That's a good and viable approach, but more complex (more steps and writing code directly), then just using min/max if that works.  Since the data is already sorted, if the order might be different than min/max, I would aggregate start/begin with "all rows" and use `List.First` and `List.Last`

Comment: I don't know even simple M-code so it's all greek to me right now...

Comment: @TimWilliams I'll add the variation to my answer

Comment: Wow these are all very helpful! I was trying to do it with VBA but these seem much simpler! Thank you!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Will do. Just one quick note I think I missed to mention. If for example 3 rows of data all have the same ID and order, but first row is class 2, second row is class 1 and third row is class 2 again. And their begin->end are continuous (second row is between first and third). At this point I don't want to consolidate the first and third row, and would like to keep it as three rows. Is this additional condition still possible using the solutions above?

Comment: @4purs I don't entirely understand your comment. Note that your request was *"consolidate rows when they have the same ID, Order, and Class"* and that is what this does.  If that is not what you really want, then you should ask a different question and lay out the specifics of exactly what you want.

Comment: I apologize I did not realize I had not been specific enough. I’ll ask a different question and select this one as the answer for this question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Option with formulas - in the simplest way, copy the table to a new location and use `Remove duplicates` to leave unique values in the `Id`, `Order`, and `Class` columns. Next fill the columns with the following formulas:

**Begin** (array formula):

`{=INDEX($C$2:$C$9,MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$9=H2)*($B$2:$B$9=I2)*($F$2:$F$9=M2),ROW($A$2:$A$9)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$9))+1)),0)}`

**End** (array formula):

`{=INDEX($D$2:$D$9,MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$9=H2)*($B$2:$B$9=I2)*($F$2:$F$9=M2),ROW($A$2:$A$9)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$9))+1)),0)}`

**Length** (conventional formula):

`=SUMPRODUCT($E$2:$E$9*($A$2:$A$9=H2)*($B$2:$B$9=I2)*($F$2:$F$9=M2))`

Array formulas after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]